# Home page alert message in multilanguage

Tags: home-page-component

I have created a alert message in Home page using VF page. My requirement is that there are many users who does not know english. I want to make alert message in multi language. How to do this please help !

Answer (score 0):

You can use Custom Labels for this. Please take a look at this document.
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=cl_about.htm&type=0

You can use the `System.Label` for messages.

Regards.

Comment: Thanks for reply ! But my requirement is, if a users is from brazil, I want to show alert message in their language. And some users is from germany they should see that same message in german language.

Comment: Yes Rahul, for that you can use Custom Labels. You need to create each for every language you have. You can also use the Translation Workbench. You can access this from you Setup --> type Translation on the Quick Find.